# OpenSSH and remote invocation

Tags: ssh, powershell, ssis

Before I ask the questions, I have to provide some context information...

I have a SSIS server which invokes a SSIS package. The SSIS package copies a file to a file server. After the copy action, the SSIS package must invoke a SFTP transfer to SFTP copy the file from the file server to another fileserver.

In schema:
SSIS Server -> File Server 1 (SSH) -> File Server 2 (SSH)

File Server 1 has the role of a SSH Client and File Server 2 as SSH Server. SSIS Server and File Server 1 are inbound (on premise) and File Server 2 outbound (off-premise).

The SSH must be OpenSSH, all servers being Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

Now the questions are:

1. Which OpenSSH software is most suitable as OpenSSH client (on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bits)?
2. Closely related to point 1: how can the OpenSSH file transfer invocation be done remotely from the SSIS server ?

Regarding point 2: There are thoughts of using PowerShell to invoke the transfer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments. RebEx SFTP is used.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) has worked well for me to script file copies. [Pscp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe) and [psftp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/psftp.exe) from [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) work just as well.  If you are insistent on using .NET libraries for the file transfer, [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) is also an option

Comment: I am using the RebEx SFTP component now, and that works perfectly. From SSIS I create one or more .ps1 (Powershell) scripts with managed RebEx commands, and then copy them to the SSH server. Then I invoke from SSIS with Powershell remoting the .ps1 file which transfers the file to the outbound SFTP server.